# iOS Core Animation - Fold a Layer

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview, core-animation

Using Core Animation, I would like to fold a `UIView` (i.e. it's `CALayer`) on it's center. i.e. I would set the anchor point as (0.5,0.5) & fold the layer. This image that I created in Photoshop might give the effect I am looking for -

[image]

So, what's happening is, the layer is being folded on its center, as the fold is happening a little bit of perspective is applied (the infamous `m34`!). Initially, the view is parallel in  X-Y plane with Z axis looking straight to the user. As the fold is happening, bottom half & top half at the same time move back (with some perspective, to give depth & 3D effect) till the entire layer is (parallel) in X-Z plane. Note that once the layer is parallel in X-Z plane, the user will no longer be able to see the Layer. But that's ok, that's the effect I am looking for. A `UIView` disappearing by folding on it's center.

How would one go about doing this in `iOS`? Without using 2 different layers (for bottom & for top)? Any help is much appreciated...

**Update:** As @miamk points out, this is the same UI effect used in **"Our Choice"** App or **"Flipboard"** App.

**UPDATE:** I have offered bounty on this to get more specific answers. Would love to see -

1. Code samples.
2. Advise from people who have done something like this.
3. Even the way to achieve this in a detailed fashion (algo) is much appreciated.

Comment: This would be something similar to Al Gore's Our Choice app (the folding and opening of images) or Flipboard's page turning animation, right? Good question, although I doubt I can be of any help.

Comment: Yes, something like that! See if you can come up with ANY idea? no matter how wacky it is...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `CALayer` is a plane, and can not be folded. Unless you write a core image filter for it, like the page curl effect, but that if private API and not an option to you.

You need to split your view into two views, and fake the fold by transforming the two `CALayer`s simultaneously.

By default a layers transform do not have perspective, so you must also setup this:

```
 transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000;
```

**OK Let's be even clearer: Split the view in two and fold them:**

Your view hiarchy according to the image you posted looks something like this:

```
+ UIView      - Root view
    + UIImageView - The persons face
    + UILabel     - The label with title
    + UILabel     - The label with company name
    + UILabel     - The label with a short description.
    + UILabel     - The label with e-mail
    + UILabel     - The label with web address
    + UILabel     - The label with phone number
```

So introduce two new views to this view hierarchy for the purpose of folding, like this:

```
+ UIView    - Root view
    + UIView      - Top half of the card
        + UIImageView - The persons face
        + UILabel     - The label with title
        + UILabel     - The label with company name
        + UILabel     - The label with a short description.
    + UIView      - Bottom half of the view
        + UILabel     - The label with e-mail
        + UILabel     - The label with web address
        + UILabel     - The label with phone number
```

Not too hard. Now animate only the two views used for grouping the top and bottom half.

I will not write the code for you, but one more vital tip to make it easy: Change the anchor points of the view to animate! You do not want to rotate them by their own centers, instead shift the center of rotation to align with the edges they have against each other.

```
 topView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 1.0f);
 bottomView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: i get the idea of splitting my view into 2 layers & run animation on it.but what happens to the original layer? How to split my `CALayer` into 2 layers? After the animation is complete, how to restore? What code you have posted, is to give perspective, I know this. The real part I needed help was to split my layer into 2 part...

Comment: @Srikar - I would not split and merge the layers all the time. I would just go for two `UIView`s that just happen to be alid out next to each other. Less fuzz.

Comment: First thanks for taking time out to discuss this.Now coming back, what you say might get ugly, as I want to do this on a `UITableViewCell`. I want to my tableViewCell to fold & disappear. With your approach I would need to provide lots of code to divide my content across 2 cells. There has to be a better way?

Comment: Well you could render the original content to a image context, and then use that image as the content of two layers. But judging by the image you have in the question that is more work for you.

Comment: yeah, looks complicated. I think i understood what you are saying. Any place, any documentation, any reading material that could help me?

Comment: Srinkar - Not really, this is basic UIKit and Core Animation stuff. Look at Apple's documentation, there is no magic trick, just doing what the API:s provide.

Comment: Adjusting `anchorPoint` is what you want, but I've found it to be a pain in the butt because it also changes the layer's frame, which is annoying. You'll have to compensate for this so that, effectively, all you did was affect the center of rotation, not modify any of the layer's geometry.

Comment: @Lucas When doing any fancy animations with a layer/view you should stay away from `frame`, instead use `bounds` and `center`/`positions`. The `frame` property is *calculated* from and to the others.

Comment: @PeyloW I don't touch the frame. However, changing the `anchorPoint` does adjust the frame, so you have to do some calculations to figure out the new center point, relative to the anchor point, in order for the layer to be in the same place it was before the `anchorPoint` as altered.

Comment: A good article explaining this process can be found here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-page-folding-animation-page-sketch-spine-fold-effect--mobile-13473

Answer (score 11):

What about this kind of workflow:

Get image from the view

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then create 2 images (top and bottom rect) using

```
CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( CGImageRef, CGRect);
```

This leaves you with the assets you need to do what you want. Dynamically created top and bottom images that can be animated.

Comment: so do I hide the original view? and place these 2 images (top,bottom) on top of the hidden view so that it appears as one & then perform the fold animation?

Answer (score 5):

Did a little research and stumbled upon this awesome project on Github: [AFKPageFlipper](https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper).
Its pretty recent, did you know about it? It's essentially Flipboard's animation done completely with just plain-and-simple Core Animation.

Take a look at it, its surprisingly easy to follow through the code, and it might just give you some direction on how to implement what you need.

Comment: @BarryWark I did. It was edited out for some reason I don't quite understand. You can still see the link prior to the revision.

Comment: @Strikar Why remove the link?

Comment: There, rolled back for ya.  Dunno why he removed it in the first place.

Comment: If you pay attention to the code, this library does what is mentioned in other answers, it splits the current layer into two images and animates the left and right layer appropriately. You can see this code in initFlip, so not really that impressive lol.